# MySql - three sucessfully joined tables, but failing to get one column result?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have three tables (user, post, comments) joined up (for an ajax powered social network thing I am doing for a degree).

So far so good but when I loop through them I am getting all the results except one. The reference to who commented on a post (stored within comments table) is coming up only as a number id (which should be joined to the user table but my join is obviously not working correctly!).

Any help very much appreciated! Probably something simple as I am still new at this PHP/mysql game!

MySQL tables:

```
           CREATE TABLE `post` (
           `pid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
           `uid` int(10) NOT NULL,
           `post` text NOT NULL,
           `pid_imageurl` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
           `likes` int(10) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`pid`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 



           CREATE TABLE `user` (
           `uid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
           `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
           `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
           `uid_imageurl` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
           `joindate` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
           ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;


           CREATE TABLE `comments` (
           `cid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
           `comment_pid` int(10) NOT NULL,
           `comment_uid` int(10) NOT NULL,
           `comment` text NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`cid`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Code:

```
        $sql = "SELECT post.post, post.pid_imageurl, post.likes, user.name, comments.comment,   
        user.uid_imageurl, comments.comment_uid

                FROM post
                INNER JOIN user
                ON post.uid=user.uid
                LEFT JOIN comments
                ON comments.comment_pid=post.pid
                AND user.uid=comments.comment_uid
                ";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);



        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){?>
        <ul>
            <li>User Profile image here:<? echo $row['uid_imageurl']; ?></li>
            <li>Post:<? echo $row['post']; ?></li>
            <li>Post by:<? echo $row['name']; ?></li>
            <li>Post images:<? echo $row['pid_imageurl']; ?></li>

            <li>post has: <? echo $row['likes']; ?> likes.</li>
            <li><? echo $row['comment']; ?></li>
            <li>by: <? echo $row['comment_uid']; ?></li>
           <!--This is only output as a stored id no rather than users name--!>




        </ul>


        <?}
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your query should be this:

```
SELECT 
    p.post, 
    p.pid_imageurl, 
    p.likes, 
    u.name, 
    c.comment,   
    u.uid_imageurl, 
    cu.name as CommentName
FROM 
    post p
    INNER JOIN user u ON 
        p.uid=u.uid
    LEFT JOIN comments c ON 
        c.comment_pid=post.pid
    left join user cu on
        c.comment_uid = cu.uid
```

And `$row['comment_uid']` should become `$row['CommentName']`.

Your original query is only grabbing comments that the original poster has made (your join condition). You want to join to the `user` table yet again to get the comment poster rather than the original poster.

Comment: Hi your code looks like a great solution but what does the cu.name relate to? and the post p/comments c and user cu? I am new to mysql.

Comment: p, c, and cu are aliases. It allows you to use them later to identify columns. In this way, you can join the `user` table twice without an issue, since you alias both of them differently.